# How to get window size from within another class?

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0

I have found [this post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8687/how-to-find-the-window-size-in-xna) explaining about how to get the size of the Window, but for whatever reason I'm having issues getting it to work inside of a Singleton class that I'm made to manage a set of Objects.  Anyone have any examples of getting these values from inside of a singleton?

EDIT:  Just in case the question gets asked.  I'm using the values for when the Manager instantiate the objects it's managing...  So that they don't all start at the same spot and to ensure they start on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1 - Provide global access to Game**

The simplest way I can think of is to provide global access to your `Game` instance:

```cs
public class MyGame : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    public static MyGame Instance;
    public MyGame () { Instance = this; }
}
```

After which you can simply do `MyGame.Instance.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds` or [any of the other alternatives Andrew suggested](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/8694/11686) in the other question. This would work from *anywhere* in your application, granted the game has already been created which should always be the case anyway.

---

**Method 2 - Pass a reference to Game to your class**

Alternatively, pass a reference to `Game` to your class. If you're using a singleton class ([do you really need to?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/12784/11686)) and your constructor needs to remain empty, use a separate `Initialize` method instead:

```cs
public class MySingleton
{
    public void Initialize(Game game) { _game = game; }
    private Game _game;
}
```

After which you can access it as `_game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds` from within your class. Don't forget to call `Initialize` when starting the game though (i.e. calling `MySingleton.Instance.Initialize(this)` from within your `Game`).

---

**Method 3 - Make your class a GameComponent**

If your manager inherits from [GameComponent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamecomponent(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx) or [DrawableGameComponent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.drawablegamecomponent.aspx), then it's already guaranteed to hold a valid reference to a `Game` object. You'll need to pass this reference to the constructor when instantiating your manager.

```
public class MyClass : GameComponent
{
    public MyClass(Game game) : base(game) { }
}
```

In this case you can access it as `Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds` from within your class.

Comment: As far as needing a Singleton? Not sure I'm mainly playing around.  Just started a Game Development class so still just playing around with the framework.  Excellent answer though.  Thank you.