# Is the viewport meant to be an absolute representation of where the underlying device is drawing?

Tags: xna, windows-forms

I know this may sound like an odd question but I just wanted to confirm which way it is.

Currently I am using XNA within Windows Forms (MDI) and I am just wondering about the viewport, as I have multiple forms with their own graphics device to draw with.

Now originally I just assumed the viewport was meant to be a basically a wrapper for the screen size (i.e., width and height), however I noticed it contains an X and Y. So then I was unsure if it was meant to directly represent the drawing region of the device.

Take for example the below scenario:

I have a forms with a panel which is docked within a group box, its relative position in the form is `{ X: 100, Y: 100, Width: 320, Height: 280 }` however its absolute position on the screen would be lets say `{ X: 400, Y: 320, Width: 320, Height: 280 }`. Then if I were to use it like I was originally assuming the panel itself which hosts the underlying handle for Xna to draw to it would be `{ X: 0, Y: 0, Width: 320, Height: 280 }`.

So if you imagine I then start dragging the window around a bit, the relative positions do not change, but obviously the absolute one would, as you could technically drag the panel off screen.

So basically the question is, do I need to use absolute positions for my viewport and update them every time the graphics device is about to be drawn, or do I use relative positions and only update when the area is resizing? and if so is it relative to the form, or is it always going to be 0,0 for the x/y in this scenario?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

The **viewport** is a rectangular region on the **backbuffer** that determines the area in which the rasteriser draws pixels. A viewport (X,Y) of (0, 0) is always the top-left corner of the backbuffer (in XNA). You can freely move and resize it *within* the backbuffer.

The **backbuffer** is the underlying surface that the GPU is drawing to. To resize it you have to reset the graphics device. It doesn't have a position of its own - it is drawn on whatever window it is attached to, using that window's position (in this case, a panel counts as a window).

When rendering, the rasteriser takes inputs in **projection space**, converting vertex positions to pixel positions within the **viewport**. The position (-1, -1) in projection space is in the bottom-left of the viewport, and (1, 1) is in the top-right. To transform the 3D vertices in your world into projection space, you use a projection matrix.

(`SpriteBatch`'s default projection matrix lets it take input coordinates in client space within the viewport.)

Here are some references about [the various things that determine display size](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/8694/288) and about [projection space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3539665/165500).

Answer (score 3):

Taken directly from the [Winforms Series](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1) samples, here's the relevant bit of code related to your question. There was also a bit of commentary in there that might be useful.

```cs
void BeginDraw()
{
    // ... other code handling device resetting

    // Many GraphicsDeviceControl instances can be sharing the same
    // GraphicsDevice. The device backbuffer will be resized to fit the
    // largest of these controls. But what if we are currently drawing
    // a smaller control? To avoid unwanted stretching, we set the
    // viewport to only use the top left portion of the full backbuffer.

    Viewport viewport = new Viewport();
    viewport.X = 0;
    viewport.Y = 0;
    viewport.Width = ClientSize.Width;
    viewport.Height = ClientSize.Height;
    viewport.MinDepth = 0;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1;
    GraphicsDevice.Viewport = viewport;

    // ...
}
```

In short, they never change the `Viewport` X and Y anywhere on the code and it still works in the scenario you described.