# XNA graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth's new value doesn't immediately change window size

Tags: xna, c#, graphics, viewport

I set the width and height of the window in my game constructor, and then pass the graphics manager to a class to check the value. In the game's initialize function, it doesn't seem to recognize the new width and height values, so it uses the default.

Here's relevant code:

**Game1.cs Constructor:**

```
graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1600;
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 900;
Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
World = new TestWorld(Content, graphics);
```

**Game1.cs Initialize**

```
World.Initialize();
```

**TestWorld Initialize**

```
Debug.WriteLine(Graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width);
```

The TestWorld Initialize outputs the default (800).

I have tried graphics.ApplyChanges(), but it does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried to add graphics.ApplyChanges(); after? It should not be mandatory when changing size in the game constructor, but you can still try.

Comment: As trivial of an answer that is it is still one. I'd recommend adding it as an answer.

Comment: @AlphSpirit I have tried the apply changes in the constructor and the game1 initialize to no avail!

Comment: @ClassicThunder See the comment from Shane. That's why I didn't post this as an answer, because I knew it was very unlikely to solve the problem.

Comment: @Shane Still, there is something fishy about that TestWorld. I have personally never seen such class in XNA... Are you using any other library with your project? Or if it is a custom class, can you please provide us with samples?

Comment: @AlphSpirit It's a custom class. This is the first code that's called. I didn't include the world constructor, which just takes the GraphicsDeviceManager parameter and stores it in a field. Then, I use that field in the World Initialize function.

Comment: Using Graphics.PreferredBackbufferWidth over Graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width works. It looks like the viewport doesn't change until base.initialize gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at [this old answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11287316/165500) that explains the process in detail.

Basically: The members on `GraphicsDeviceManager` are settings that are  only actually applied when `ApplyChanges` ***or*** `CreateDevice` is called. Note that `CreateDevice` will get called for you if you are using the built-in `Game` class.

---

Regarding additional questions asked in comments: The graphics device (and so `GraphicsDevice.Viewport`) is not guaranteed to be available until `LoadContent` gets called ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.loadcontent.aspx)).

Although you can usually get away with using it in `Initialize`, that is not strictly correct (it does not play nice if the graphics device gets reset).

---

The correct way to get the window/viewport size is described in detail in [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/8694/288).

I think you might need to restructure your code so that things get set up in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `graphics.ApplyChanges();` in order to apply your updated settings.

Comment: I've tried this already. Doesn't seem to help. I've added it in the Game1 Constructor and the World Initialize

Comment: Strange, it works for me in my Initalize() function. It isn't called immediately, but at the end of my Initalize(), after logging messages to the log file and loading the settings config. Maybe you need to wait a little while before calling it.

Comment: I wonder if the changes are applied in the base.Initialize() for the game class... Not sure how I would get around that without moving around my functions.